# Get the first <ul> element from the post body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use Javascript or jQuery to get the first `<ul>` element the post body and display it. On Blogger, the tag `<data:post.body/>` displays the whole post.

```
<div class="post-cover">
    <img src="BIG-IMAGE"/>
</div>

<ul>
   <li>CONTENT 1</li>
   <li>CONTENT 2</li>
   <li>CONTENT 3</li>
   <li>CONTENT 4</li>
</ul>
```

The reason is: I need these ul elements to display in the homepage, but I cannot load the original image because they are all large and would affect the loading time dramatically.

I also cannot use `display: none` for the image because it loads the same way. I'm using Blogger.

I think it is similar when getting a thumbnail (first src) or the first string (for summaries) but I don't know how to make it.

Comment: You are trying to preload the images. and the way you are trying is seems to be wrong. search for `preloading images` choose the best one.

Comment: It may not necessarily be wrong. Depending on his desired result.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Your questions title references a `ul` but the body of the question references images.

Comment: Close the .post-cover div tag for starters.

Comment: I've organized better the question. The ul elements are not in a div. But the image is in a div in case there is a way not to load them. I just need to get the first <ul> and display it

Comment: Please explain what you mean by display it. From the code you have it will already be displayed...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 
ul:first gets the first ul element on the page.

```
  $("ul:first").css(//whatever you want to do);
```

You can use `$("ul:first")` to get the ul and use any jquery function to work with that element.

Comment: If there are other `ul` this will select them also. OP specifically said "from a div"

Comment: post-cover is class not Id .. but ul in OP html code is not have a parent post-cover

Comment: It is surounded by post-cover, he just did not close his div tag

Comment: he already closed div tag after img not after ul :) .. that why I delete my answer

Comment: No biggie. Looks like he has lots of options.

Comment: I've organized better the question. The div is only for the image. The rest of the post body isn't in a div.

Comment: What do you mean display it? I edited for everything except to display it.

Comment: The code must return only the first <ul>. That's what I mean with display it

Comment: I have 4K posts in my site, all of them are the same style. So I cannot apply id="List" in all.. Isn't there a way to make it automatically? Like I said, with the first ul.

Comment: This will only get the first ul:   $("ul:first")

Answer (score 0):

As the post title says - get the first  element from a div (and display it, using jQuery):

`$( ".post-cover ul" ).first().show();`

Preload images, which it seems you may be trying to actually do:

```
$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}
$.preloadImages("BIG-IMAGE.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

> to get the first element of a div

In your case, that's an `img` but not a `ul` tag.

If you really want to get the first element whatever it is, you can do it this way:

```
$(".post-cover").children().first().css({ // ... });
```

jQuery children() takes all children in DOM
jQuery first() takes the first one of them

However, if you know which element you are going to take, it is better to give him a name and access it using a name:

```
// HTML
<div class="post-cover">
   <img src="BIG-IMAGE" id="post-cover-image"/>
</div>

// JS 
$("#post-cover-image").css({ // ... });
```

Comment: Yeldar, it is not about the image, but the ul. The <ul> elements are not in a div, so that's why it should get the first ul. I've organized better the question

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the image element of the div which like this :

```
var div_post_cover = document.getElementsByClassName("post-cover")[0];
```

Note : [0] is for the first DIV that have a class of **post-cover**

Then you need to get the first element inside the DIV and code was like this :

```
var img_first = div_post_cover.children[0];
```

or

```
var img_first = div_post_cover.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Then you will get the value of the src

```
var img_first_src = img_first.src;
```

This will be the summarized code.

```
var img_src = document.getElementsByClassName("post-cover")[0].children[0].src;
```

You need to try this if works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = (function(){
            //document.getElementsByClassName("post-cover")[0].children[0].src
            alert(document.getElementsByClassName("post-cover")[0].children[0].src);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The <ul> isn't in a div, only the image. So there is no children.. That's why it should automatically pick up the first <ul> element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show()` and `hide()` :

```
$( ".post-cover ul:first" ).hide();
$( ".post-cover ul:first" ).show();
```

Comment: .post-cover does not contain the ul.